# Easiest flow authentication with Reactjs + Electron (without any special services)

Tags: reactjs, authentication, react-router, electron

I'm trying to create a desktop application (Reactjs + Electron) with a very simple authentication (forms + personal back-end).
But I don't know how to make a correct and safe navigation flow between my authentication pages and my app's pages and I can't find solutions on the internet.

I'm a beginner to reactJS + Electron but currently, I can navigate between two forms (sign-in & sign-up) I need help to validate these forms and to navigate to my app's pages with another router flow.

app.js (sign in class) :

```
class SignInClic extends React.Component {
 get show() {
  return this.props.activeSection === "SignIn";
 }

 render() {
  if (this.show) {
   return <SignIn/>;
  } else { 
   return null;}
  }
}

class SignIn extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
   mail: '', pwd: ''
  };
  this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
 }

 handleSubmit(event) {
  const { mail, pwd } = this.state;
  var details = {'email': mail, 'passwd': pwd };
  var formBody = [];

  for (var property in details) { 
    var encodedKey = encodeURIComponent(property);
    var encodedValue = encodeURIComponent(details[property]);
    formBody.push(encodedKey + "=" + encodedValue);
  }
  formBody = formBody.join("&");

  fetch('http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:8083/connect', { method: 'POST', headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'}, body: formBody }).then(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 500 || response.status === 200) {
    return response.json()
  }
}).then(function(object) {
  console.log('login success')
})

}
render() {
return (
  <div className="masterBox">
    <div className="slaveBox SignIn">
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <img src={logo} alt="logo"/>
        <h1>Project</h1>
        <input type="mail" name="mail" placeholder="email" required/>
        <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Password" required/>
        <button type="submit">Sign-in</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
)
}}
```

app.js (sign up class) :

```
class SignUpClic extends React.Component {
  get show() {
   return this.props.activeSection === "SignUp";
  }

 render() {
  if (this.show) {
    return <SignUp/>;
  } else {
    return null;
  }}
 }

class SignUp extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
 super(props);
 this.state = {
   mail01: '', mail02: '',
   pwd01: '', pwd02: '',
   lastName: '', license: ''
 };
this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
}

handleSubmit(event) {
const { mail01, mail02, pwd01, pwd02, lastName } = this.state;

if (mail01 && pwd01 && mail01 === mail02 && pwd01 === pwd02) {
  var details = {'email': mail01, 'passwd': pwd01, 'lastname': lastName };
  var formBody = [];
  for (var property in details) {
    var encodedKey = encodeURIComponent(property);
    var encodedValue = encodeURIComponent(details[property]);
      formBody.push(encodedKey + "=" + encodedValue);
    }
    formBody = formBody.join("&");

    fetch('http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:8083/register', { method: 'POST', headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'}, body: formBody }).then(function(response) {
      if (response.status === 500 || response.status === 200) {
        return response.json()
      }
    }).then(function(object) {
      console.log('subscription success')
  })
} else if (!mail01 || !mail02 || mail01 !== mail02) {
  console.log('Error : Email looks wrong')
} else if (!pwd01 || !pwd02 || pwd01 !== pwd02) {
  console.log('Error : Pwd looks wrong')
} else {
  console.log('Error : Unknown')
}

}
render() {
return (
  <div className="masterBox">
    <div className="slaveBox SignUp">
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <img src={logo} alt="logo"/>
        <h1>Project</h1>
        <input type="mail" name="mail01" placeholder="Your email" required/>
        <input type="mail" name="mail02" placeholder="Same email" required/>
        <input type="password" name="pwd01" placeholder="Your Password" required/>
        <input type="password" name="pwd02" placeholder="Same Password" required/>
        <input type="text" name="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" required/>
        <input type="text" name="license" placeholder="License number (if purchased)" title="XXXX-XXXX-XXXX"/>
        <button type="submit">Sign-up</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
)
}}
```

app.js (routage) :

```
 const Main = ({ activeSection }) => (
  <React.Fragment>
   <SignInClic activeSection={activeSection} />
   <SignUpClic activeSection={activeSection} />
  </React.Fragment>
 ); 

 const MainOptions = ({ onToggle }) => (
   <div className="MainOptions">
     <button name="SignUp" onClick={onToggle}>Sign-up</button>
     <button name="SignIn" onClick={onToggle}>Sign-in</button>
   </div>
  );

  class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      activeSection: "SignIn"
    };

    this.handleToggleSection = this.handleToggleSection.bind(this);
  }

  handleToggleSection(e) {
   const { name } = e.target;
   this.setState(() => ({
    activeSection: name
   }));
   }

   render() {
return (
  <div className="App">
    <MainOptions onToggle={this.handleToggleSection} />
    <Main activeSection={this.state.activeSection} />
  </div>
);
}}
export default App;
```

thank you for your help and patience.